# C/C++ Windows - ExtractIcon() not retrieving icon for all executables

Tags: c++, c, windows, api, icons

Here's just the snippet of what I'm doing:

```
PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)   return;

if(!Process32First( hProcessSnap, &pe32))
{
        CloseHandle(hProcessSnap); // clean the snapshot object
         return;
 }    

do
{
     hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
     HICON icon = ExtractIcon((HINSTANCE)hProcess, pe32.szExeFile, 0);
}
while(Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));
```

Why does it work for some programs and not for others?  It's basically only those, notepad, and the cmd prompt it gets icons for, no other programs.

Comment: chrome uses one process per tab frame(AFAIK). It's normal then that the tab's frame does not contain any icon at all.

Comment: Yea I know chrome isn't the greatest example but was in the ss.  It's just not doing it at all from trillian or any other programs which have an icon either.

Comment: The code is missing all required error handling so you don't know why it doesn't work.  You cannot hope to be able to open all processes with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, that asks for way too many privileges.

Comment: Error codes are mostly 2 ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, with a few 1813 ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`ExtractIcon()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648068.aspx) function is designed to extract icons embedded in the executable/DLL as a resource (e.g. the icon is part of the `.exe` or `.dll` file).  If the icon is dynamically loaded by the application (e.g. from a file using [`LoadImage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045.aspx)) , then you can't retrieve it using `ExtractIcon()`.

That easily explains why you can't get the icon for Chrome tabs since they usually download the icon from a website and then display it.  I would also suspect that any application that supports custom skinning is unlikely to allow you to extract its icon, or at best give you only the default icon.